# ExtJS authentication

Tags: authentication, extjs4

I'm tring to authenticate user to have access to page from extJS. I saw some examples how to do it, but I'm still getting 'authentication required' error. How should I do it?

Here's my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var auth = "Basic " + 'user' + ':' + 'password';

    // Create store          
    var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // Load data at once
        autoLoad: true,
        // Override default http proxy settings
        proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
            // Call web service method using GET syntax
            url: 'http://myotherdomain.com/something.xml',
            headers : { Authorization : auth }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more information to work from. This only demonstrates how you're loading a store. Could you show us the code that calls this store and actually performs the authentication?

Comment: @Eric Cook, 
I've updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trouble was caused because phrase login:password wasn't encoded, there was sended pure string. When I encoded it with Base64 authentication was accepted.